# Ordinal-universal linear order on $\kappa$ elements

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, posets

The starting point of this question is the observation that if $\lambda$ is a countable ordinal, then there is an order-embedding $e:\lambda \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

Given an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, is there a linearly ordered set $L_\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$ such that for every ordinal $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=\kappa$ there is an embedding $e:\alpha \hookrightarrow L_\kappa$?

Comment: I think this question has come up on MO and M.SE a few times in the past.

Comment: See this question, and also the reference mentioned in Andreas Blass's answer there: https://mathoverflow.net/a/57599/1946

Comment: But I see, you are asking only about universality for the well-orders, not all linear orders of size $\kappa$. I'm not sure whether that requires full universality...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an infinite cardinal. Give $[\lambda]^{<\omega}$ the linear ordering $\leq$ where we set $A>B$ if there is some $\alpha\in B$ where $\alpha\cap A=\alpha\cap B$ and $\alpha\not\in A$.

We shall show using what is essentially transfinite induction that every ordinal less than $\lambda^+$ embeds into $[\lambda]^{<\omega}$. Suppose that $\alpha$ is the least ordinal where $\alpha$ does not embed into $\lambda^+$. Clearly $\alpha>0$. If $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal, then $\alpha=\beta+1$ for some $\beta$ and there is some embedding $f:\beta\rightarrow[\lambda]^\omega$. Now, define $g:\alpha\rightarrow[\lambda]^\omega$ by letting
$g(\delta)=\{0\}\cup\{1+\sigma\mid \sigma\in f(\delta)\}$ whenever $\delta<\alpha$ and by letting $g(\beta)=\emptyset$. Then $g$ is an order preserving embedding, so $\alpha$ cannot embed into $\lambda^+$. Now suppose that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. Then let $(x_\beta)_{\beta<\gamma}$ be a cofinal continuous increasing sequence in $\alpha$ with $x_0=0$ where $\gamma$ is a cardinal with $\gamma\leq\lambda$. Then for each $\beta<\gamma$, let
$f_\beta:[x_\beta,x_{\beta+1})\rightarrow[\lambda]^{<\omega}$ be an embedding. Then define an embedding $f:\alpha\rightarrow[\lambda]^{<\omega}$ by letting
$f(x)=\{\beta\}\cup\{\beta+1+\delta\mid \delta\in f_\beta(x)\}$ whenever $x\in[x_\beta,x_{\beta+1})$.

Observe that $[\lambda]^n$ is a well-ordered of order type $\lambda^n$ whenever $n\in\omega$. Therefore $[\lambda]^{<\omega}$ is the union of countably many well-ordered sets. Every totally ordered set $X$ which is the union of countably many well-ordered sets has no descending sequence of length $\omega_1$. Therefore, $[\lambda]^{<\omega}$ has no descending sequence of length $\omega_1$.

Comment: This is great, but I don't think you've defined the order properly, since as you've stated it, it is not a linear order, as any two sets with the same least element will not be related by your order. I think you want to use something like the lexical order in the increasing enumeration, that is,  comparing first the least elements of $A$ and $B$, and then the next least elements, etc. This will give the right order of the sets appearing in your $f_\beta$ argument, since you want all the sets with least element $\beta$ to be judged based on the rest of the set.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I fixed the definition of the linear ordering. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

Let me mention one easy observation, which is that the order $2^{<\kappa}$ is universal for all linear orders of size $\kappa$. View the order as $\{-1,1\}^{<\kappa}$, where strings are ordered lexically, so that at the first difference, if the digit is $-1$ it is lower, and if $1$ it is higher. This is the same as the Surreal number line, generating for birthdays up to $\kappa$.

It often happens in set theory that $2^{<\kappa}$ has size $\kappa$, in which case this order is a linear order of size $\kappa$ that is universal for all linear orders of size $\kappa$. For example, this is true for $\kappa=\omega$, and it is true for any $\kappa$ under the generalized continuum hypothesis.

Meanwhile, it is consistent with ZFC that $2^{<\kappa}$ is strictly bigger than $\kappa$, and in these cases this order is larger than desired. There are quite subtle set-theoretic issues arising in these cases, discussed in the references mentioned at the other question, mentioned in the comments.

Lastly, you had asked for universality with respect to the ordinals of size $\kappa$, rather than all linear orders of size $\kappa$. I find it interesting to wonder whether these are the same---if a linear order of size $\kappa$ is universal for ordinals up to $\kappa^+$, must it be universal for all linear orders of size $\kappa$?

Comment: Thanks Joel - and your question at the end of your answer would deserve a MO post of its own.

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate your support. But I believe that question I had asked is answered by Joseph's answer here (once that answer is corrected to have the right order), and also that Joseph's answer fully answers your question here, whereas mine is only a partial answer. So I think you should accept his answer rather than mine, once he makes the corrections to make it a linear order, which I believe is possible.